# Any shortcut for -> condition ? ['yes'] : ['yes', 'no'] in dart?

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

```
condition ? ['yes'] : ['yes', 'no']
```

looking for any shortcut for above snippet in dart like ['yes', if(condition)'no']

Comment: So you are looking for something even shorter than `['yes', if(condition)'no']`?

Comment: No, i just gave an eg: ['yes', if(condition)'no'] which doesn't worked in dart. it takes both 'yes' and 'no' anyway.

Comment: actually it worked .... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Dart 2.3, you can use the inline if statement:

```
['yes', if(!condition) 'no']
```

You can read more about this feature here: [collection if](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists)